# What do you call the action of take a number instead of waiting in line or queue?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there a word describing this action?

What is the name of the machine that provides you a ticket with your number or priority turn? you don't wait in line/queue in order, just take a seat and wait to be called by this number, code or even your name.

Also, need to know the name of the display where you see the last turn called.

Thanks

EDIT:
I supposed to replicate this in a software system. The term Kiosk applies here?

Comment: It's called *taking a number*. They're called *take-a-number dispensers* and you wait your turn and watch the *now serving* sign. I do not know a single word for either of these.

Comment: Do you need the term for the name of a class or function or is this name something users will see?

Comment: @CandiedOrange it was for documentation propose, thanks.

Comment: Note that "how do you call" is not English. It is always "What do you call".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a *ticket dispenser*. Here's [one for sale](http://www.webstaurantstore.com/turn-o-matic-d900-red-gray-take-a-number-ticket-dispenser/730D900.html) that I found on the web (I'm not knowingly affiliated with the vendor).

> **Dispenser** *noun*
>   1.2 [usually with modifier] An automatic machine or container which is designed to release a specific amount of something: *a paper towel dispenser*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dispenser)

The word [kiosk](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/kiosk) is more evocative of a booth or small room, so it's not as appropriate as *dispenser* for the device itself. Ticket dispensers are often either free-standing or bolted to a wall, but if it was placed in a small room, possibly with someone in that space doing the dispensing, that *room* could be called the ticket *kiosk*. The machine itself would still be called a dispenser, though.

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering if the term kiosk applies, see my edit. Thanks again.

Comment: @Horaciux I've edited my answer to discuss the term 'kiosk'.

Comment: Specifically, a kiosk refers to something a person stands inside (or can stand inside), not a machine.